# mysql search date range between data range

Tags: php, mysql

I have database having data as follows:

```
+------------+------------+---------+
| startdate  |   enddate  | hotelID |
+------------+------------+---------+
| 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-14 |    1    |
| 2017-01-15 | 2017-01-20 |    1    |
| 2017-01-21 | 2017-01-25 |    1    |
+------------+------------+---------+
```

I now want to search date range `2017-01-13` to `2017-01-22`

I am having problem get this done.

Desired result will pick all 3 columns since selected date range as presence in all dates

Comment: Where is the problematic select between statement?

Comment: this question shows no effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to fit exactly or can any range work? If so then the following would return all three rows:

```
SELECT * WHERE enddate > '2017-01-13' AND startdate < '2017-01-22'
```

The enddate needs to be bigger than the start of your range, and the start date has to be smaller than the end of your range.